# Redirect to a JSP using AJAX upon completion

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am very new to AJAX and I am stuck with a problem. I have a `<div>` in my JSP. I have another JSP that is included in the above JSP using `<jsp:include>`. The problem is that the included JSP does DB operations and it takes a lot of time to render. I want the former JSP to be loaded first and then latter JSP to be rendered in the DIV. I searched but couldn't understand how to resolve it. Basically, I want the former JSP to be displayed and then the latter to be displayed once it completes operations. Currently, the former JSP takes lots of time to load as the latter is included in the former JSP and will render only when the latter JSP has completed loading.

Appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not the correct approach . The DB interaction part should be done by the DAO classes triggered by some Servlet . Using JSP for DB interactions is bad . Having said that your current problem can be solved by the below approach :

1. Remove all the DB operations from the JSP.
2. Keep a `div` inside your main JSP.
3. On load , trigger an AJAX call to a Servlet.
4. Servlet/DAO class performs the DB operations and returns back the result. Store the result in `session` if needed.
5. Inside the success handler of the AJAX request function , write a call back function which loads the other JSP file.

Check this answer [Load a jsp page using AJAX load method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987391/load-a-jsp-page-using-ajax-load-method).

Answer (score 0):

The popular approach is to use javascript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and invoke the long-running operation using ajax

```
$.ajax('/longrunningop', {
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'a=1&b=2'}).done(function(data) {
    // code to display data to div here..
  });
```

Good practice is you code the long running operation to return JSON instead of JSP